# Principal factors of an inverse semigroup $S$ are Brandt semigroup except for the kernel, which is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, inverse-semigroups

This is the exercise problem of John.M. Howie book **5.4**

Let $S$ be an semigroup and $J(a)$ is denoted as a principal ideal generated by $a$, where $a \in S.$  Two element $a, b$ are $\mathcal J$ related iff $J(a) = J(b)$ and two classes $J_a \leq J_b$ iff $J(a) \subseteq J(b)$. The minimal $\mathcal J$- class is called kernel of $S$ and it is denoted by $K(S)$. $K(S), J_a \cup  \{0\}$ are the principal factors  of $S$.

Use Theorem 3.1.6, every principal factor besides kernel is either $0$-simple or null semigroup. $J_a \cup \{0\}$ is not a null semigroup, because  $a^{-1} \in J_a$ and $aa^{-1}a = a$. so $J_a \cup \{0\}$ is $0$-simple semigroup. I know that every completely $0$-simple inverse semigroup is isomorphic to Brandt semigroup. It is enough to show that $J_a \cup \{0\}$ contains a primitive idempotent.

How to prove that $J_a \cup \{0\}$ contains primitive idempotents?

Comment: Sorry to say, but this question is probably getting no replies because it is not self-contained. What book? (Howie has at least two.) What are we assuming from $S$? What is $a$? What is the exercise about?

Comment: It's John Howie not James too

Comment: This is from J. Howie *Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory*, and its asks to deduce that the principal factors of an inverse semigroup are all Brandt semigroups. But this exercise confuses me too, as for example the bicyclic semigroup is inverse and all elements are $\mathcal D$- (and hence $\mathcal J$) related, so it equals its kernel (which is a principal factor) and it has not primitive idempotent. Maybe it is a typo/lost assumption. But I am also just learning the subject, so not totally sure if I overlooked something. Maybe someone more competent could give his opinion....